# Where can I find documentation for the Blender Game Engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, documentation

where to look documentation for the following?
getCurrentScene,hitPosition,worldPosition,and others?

Comment: Please consider using [google (or similar)](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=blender+game+engine+api+manual+documentation&oq=blender+game+engine+api+manual+documentation).

Comment: Why not look in the manual? [getcurrentscene()](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.logic.html#general-functions), [worldposition](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=worldposition#bge.types.KX_GameObject.worldPosition), [hitposition](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_RaySensor.html?highlight=hitposition#bge.types.KX_RaySensor.hitPosition) etc.

Answer (score 2):

The official [Blender/BGE API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/)

Check section *[Game Engine Modules](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/#game-engine-modules)* specifically *[Game Logic (bge.logic)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.logic.html)*